# bootstrap date/time picker not working well in modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

am using  [this bootsrap date/time picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and i seem to have problems when using it within a modal.
every time i click the date icon to pick date, it resets all the form elements.has anyone come across this problem, and how i can solve it.
your help highly appreciated

here is how i have initialized it in my code:

```
$('#action_date').datetimepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR',
     pickSeconds: false, 
    startDate: new Date(),      

 });
```

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/133. That may actually be you lodging the issue. Either way, itll be fixed im sure.

Answer (score 3):

pass this steps

1. assign Css to your input to put it out of your modal form ( for see what's happen when you click on input )
2. click on input to open date/time picker
3. select that div with firebug selector
4. copy one of that div class and assign z-index:1000000 to it

you can check this code

```
bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
 z-index: 100000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_date_picker").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        autoclose: true,   
        viewMode: "years",
        minViewMode: "years"        
    }).on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Works great :)